# Licensing question about using OpenJDK to build and run

Tags: licensing, gpl, gpl-2, java

I have a small java application which I was building with Oracle JDK till now. Now I am migrating this application to OpenJDK11 and am bit confused with the licensing. I am using RedHat distribution of the OpenJDK to build my jar file. I am planning to bundle the RedHat's OpenJDK11 zip file along with my app and use the JVM to run this Jar file. I am not building the JDK itself rather using the prebuilt binaries. In that case, apart from bundling all the license text present in OpenJDK11, do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Are you bundling the OpenJDK with your app because your app won't run with another JVM, or do you do it as a convenience for your users?